# Is there an html "location" element?

Tags: html, gps

[The HTML5 `time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-time-element.html#the-time-element) looks pretty cool, but I'm wondering if there's such thing as a `location` or `place` element. It may be useful in GPS applications or the like?

Comment: I guess the short answer would be no, but technically I think it'd be possible to use `<location>`. Google uses a `<g>` element, and I don't think that exists in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<location>` element doesn't exist. I for one would agree that semantically it'd be great for web apps that involve some sort of GPS.

If I understand correctly, HTML5 allows you create [custom elements](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/explainer/index.html#custom-element-section) which may be a temporary fix for an up-and-coming web app. Semantically I don't think this is the greatest thing (all that extra markup to create an element) but some may use it. [Eric Meyer also has an article discussing custom elements](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/03/28/customizing-your-markup/).

Technically though, I think that most browsers will render unknown markup given the proper CSS and/or JavaScript ...

---

#### March 2014 update

[Custom elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) are making their way through the W3C and they are actually pretty nifty.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no location element per se in HTML5. Have a look at this though: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no such element specified that I've heard of.

Here is [a list](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/) of elements available in the HTML5 spec. *(Update: the list is based on the spec as it was in February 2009, so it is somewhat old, but there is still no `location` element that I know of.)*

Comment: Not giving a solution. Should be a comment.

Comment: @Starx It might not be a solution, but is there a solution to give? The question is if there is such an element, and the answer is no.

Comment: I dont know, may be you could point to the right direction as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such element called "location".

You can show your GPS data in HTML using [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/)

```
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.49, -0.12),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   </script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what @TestSubject528491 was getting at.